# Why the hash command in bash always returns true for ./<something>

Tags: linux, bash

Why the hash command returns 0 for this

```
$ hash -r 

$ ls -l ./kkk
./kkk: No such file or directory

$ hash ./kkk
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hash` utility will return true if the given utility is found in `$PATH` after doing a path search for it.

Since you give the name of the utility with a path, the shell would *not* do a path search for it, but instead use the path that you provided (`./`).  It's not until the shell actually tries to *run* the utility at that path that it discovers that it doesn't exist.

[The POSIX specification for `hash`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/hash.html) says

> If utility contains one or more `<slash>` characters, the results are unspecified.

... and `bash` obviously implements the unspecified behaviour as "if no path search needs to happen to find the utility, return a zero exit status".

Comment: In [source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/hash.def#n175), the first check for each path is `if (absolute_program (w)) continue;` where `absolute_program` checks for the presence of a slash. So if there is a slash, the exit status (which defaults to 'success') never gets changed.